# load() responds correctly, but html not loaded into div

Tags: jquery

I have an AJAX request to `post-bid.php` that is the result of this call:

```
$('#alert-container').load("post-bid.php", data);
```

According to firebug, this AJAX request returns the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {alert("My alert")}); </script>
```

I have this line of code above `load()` line:

```
<div id="alert-container"></div>
```

Yet no HTML is loaded into this div. Any ideas?

**SOLUTION**: I simply needed to return data to the callback function of `load()`.

Comment: Is there post-bid.php the right path? Maybe you call this file from some other url like /article/etc.html and you'll have to put the right path like /files/php/post-bid.php

Comment: please post more of you code. this is kinda confusing

Comment: try passing an explicit callback to `load()`, it might help you track down the problem.

Comment: I tried `$('#alert-container').load("post-bid.php", data, function() { alert('Load was performed.'); });` and no `load was performed` alert appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I couldn't get it to work either but I put a `document.ready` around the load code and it worked.

**HTML**

```
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

**Contents of test1.html**

```
{"result": "true"}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#click').click(function(){
        $.getJSON("test1.html", function(data){
            if (data["result"] == "true") {
                alert("My alert");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't my problem. I have the js wrapped in an action that gets called on a button click.

Comment: I've just tried it after a button click and that seems to be working too, I'll edit my answer and post the code.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you all I can think is that there is a problem with what your php script returns. My test wasn't done via a web server

Comment: Although if you just want to show an alert after a button is clicked then you don't need to do an AJAX request. I've edited my post to show what you could do instead

Comment: Ah I've just read your comment on his post, you want the alert to show  conditionally based on the results of the php script. I will change my answer to reflect this

Comment: If you return JSON from your PHP script you can use that to decide whether the alert should show. I'm just hardcoding the result to be true, but of course, you can make this dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If the content you receive is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            alert("My alert")
    });
</script>
```

Your `div` is empty because you did not receive any Html but only the script content, which is stripped out before the content is passed to the `.html()` of the target element.

Did you expect the script content to be rendered in the `#alert-container` div or did you expect for the script to execute during the `.load()` request?

**Edit**

> What's a good way to make an alert conditionally pop up, based on some
>   php that's run in the AJAX request?

According to the `load()` http://api.jquery.com/load/, it seems you could use the callback to assert the return value and then pop up the alert if the call was successful.   The success callback is executed after any html which is returned is rendered into the target element.

```
$('#alert-container').load("post-bid.php", data, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
    // textStatus = 'success' if the call was successful.
    if(textStatus == 'success'){
        alert("My alert");
    }
});
```

In addition if you look at the bottom of the documentation there is an example on how to deal with errors too.

**Edit**

> I don't want the alert to pop up when the AJAX request succeeds. I
>   want the alert to pop up after some php code requested by the AJAX has
>   run. It is from this php code, and not from the load() function, that
>   I want the alert to originate

In that case I would reconsider the design. Your php should only return the message to display and let the calling code worry about `how` to display it.

You can use an [**ajax post**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for that.

```
$.post('post-bid.php', data, function(message){
    if(message.length > 0)
    {
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I expected the script element to be rendered into the `#alert-container`. What's a good way to make an alert conditionally pop up, based on some php that's run in the AJAX request?

Comment: @RosePerrone: I edited the answer adding some information on using the callback which looks like one way to solve this.

Comment: My apologies for not being more clear. I don't want the alert to pop up when the AJAX request succeeds. I want the alert to pop up after some php code requested by the AJAX has run. It is from this php code, and not from the load() function, that I want the alert to originate. Because php is, of course, server-side, I need to generate the script for the alert and include it in a div.

Comment: @RosePerrone: In this case the it would be better to not return the script to show the message but the message itself as `responseText`. So your php page either returns an empty string or the message. You ajax call can then be a simple `.post()`and alert the message if there is one.